# how to get all the documents in collection from mongoDB using spring

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I was trying to get all the documents from a collection in mongoDB , I am using spring.

```
MongoTemplate  mongoOperation = SpringMongoConfig1.mongoTemplate()
```

Here in monngoOperation I did not find any method which returns all the docs from a collection .
can anyone help in this ?

Comment: How about [MongoOperations$findall](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#findAll-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find all the documents of JavaDocumentName(any collection name in java)

```
List<JavaDocumentName> listRes = mongoOperation.findAll(JavaDocumentName.class);
```

Comment: What if you have 100Million data in db? I think it will cause OutOfMemory Error.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
//If you don't need connection's configures. i.e. your mongo is in you localhost at 127.0.0.1:27017
MongoClient cliente = new MongoClient(); //to connect into a mongo DB

MongoDatabase mongoDb = client.getDatabase("DBname");  //get database, where DBname is the name of your database

MongoCollection<Document> robosCollection = mongoDb.getCollection("collectionName"); //get the name of the collection that you want

MongoCursor<Document> cursor =  robosCollection.find().cursor();//Mongo Cursor interface implementing the iterator protocol

    cursor.forEachRemaining(System.out::println); //print all documents in Collection using method reference
```